# Can I embed Strawberry Perl in a VC++ 6.0 compiled application or use Inline::C with the compiler mismatch?

Tags: perl, visual-c++, mingw, visual-c++-6, strawberry-perl

I am looking at embedding perl 5.10 in a large C++ application compiled with VC++ 6.0.  This leads to two questions.

1) Is it a bad idea to simply use Strawberry Perl as a dependency rather than compile my own perl with VC++ 6.0?  Would Strawberry even work given the compiler mismatch?  I presume Strawberry is compiled with mingw.  I would much rather not have to keep my own custom perl build around.

2) If I went the Strawberry route, would something like Inline::C work in the embedded application?  You'd have VC++ 6.0 code calling mingw compiled Strawberry in turn calling user mingw compiled code.  Inline::C would be an awesome capability for what I'm trying to achieve with the embedded perl interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the uncertainty involved, I would recommend compiling Perl using MSVC instead of experimenting with Strawberry Perl for this application.  There are instructions in [perlwin32](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlwin32.html) and a [related discussion](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=346164) on [Perl Monks](http://perlmonks.org/) to guide you.

As a former release manager for Strawberry Perl, I can tell you it's not terribly difficult to do if you're comfortable with a compiler already.

-- xdg

Comment: But a custom compiled win32 perl is lacking compared to Strawberry.  No integrated cpan and mingw stuff.  Can I easily get Inline::C working with my own win32 perl?

Comment: Strawberry just *packages* MinGW.  It's "configured" during compilation. So a custom compiled win32 perl will compile stuff from CPAN using the MSVC you compiled perl with.  And "integrated" CPAN is just pre-configured CPAN.  You can copy \strawberry\perl\lib\CPAN\Config.pm and adapt as needed.

Comment: But I definitely don't want to have to put MSVC on the client machines.  I'd like to use a neatly packaged mingw without any license annoyances.  Is it even possible to load mingw compiled object code into the MSVC compiled perl?

Answer (score 2):

Activestate perl is compiled with VC++ 6.0. It can use VC++ 6.0 or MinGW to compile modules since they link to the same C runtime library, msvcrt.dll. It would be preferable to use MinGW because VC++ 6.0 is neither free nor readily available (unless you can be sure that it is installed on the target machine.) [You can PPM install Mingw now](http://www.openkomodo.com/blogs/troyt/ppm-install-mingw), and compile modules from CPAN. A large number of modules compile without trouble. You may have to configure CPAN with:

o conf yaml_module '' (Two single quotes, nothing between)

o conf commit

Inline::C works.